# Hidden input field value should be changed according to the drop box selection

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

This my script code. There's something wrong with it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#type').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#type').val('Workshop'))
            $('#color').val('Orange'));
        else if ($('#type').val('Social'))
            $('#color').val('Green');
        else if ($('#type').val('Other'))
            $('#color').val('Red'));

    });
});
```

Below is the form of drop box and hidden field.

```
{!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Workshop' => 'Workshop', 'Social' => 
    'Social','Other' => 'Other'), 'type', ['id' => 'type']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('color','', ['id' => 'color']) !!}
```

Comment: add more info to OP better add the html as well.

Comment: What about my script code?

Comment: i dont see anything unusual. how are you adding the select?are you adding dynamically?what is happening with this code?add more info

Comment: When I select a value from drop box, hidden input field of form value should be changed as the above script.

Comment: Yeah. But from the drop box even if I select anything it always selected Workshop in drop box. I guess something wrong with script

Comment: i think the OP is dup of @ZakariaAcharki link posted ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the code in your JavaScript function to do a valid check, e.g.

```
if ( $(this).val() == 'Workshop' )
    $('#color').val('Orange'));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value then compare it with strings ('Workshop','Social','Other'), `$('#type').val('Workshop')` will assign the value `Workshop` to the `#type` element :

```
$(function() {
    $('#type').on('change', function() {
        var selected_option = $(this).val();

        if (selected_option == 'Workshop')
            $('#color').val('Orange'));
        else if (selected_option == 'Social')
            $('#color').val('Green');
        else if (selected_option == 'Other')
            $('#color').val('Red'));

    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

val('Workshop') changes the value of the input. 
You can use this:

```
    if ( this.value=='Workshop' )
        $('#color').val('Orange'));
```

or

```
        if ( $(this).val()=='Workshop' )
        $('#color').val('Orange'));
```